# Why does Latex add arbitrary spacing between equations when using multicolumn?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, formatting, line-spacing, multicolumn

After using multicolumn to divide up the page into three columns, some of my equations massive space in between the texts

For example: The left most column, we see that there are spaces between the equations separated by the equality sign

[image]

But this does not apply for many other equations, most of them are able to have standard spacing i.e. $A = B$ (<---wait, why doesn't inline math work here?)

Is there a way to cut down the spaces between the equations?

Comment: Please provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (Minimal Working Example) The answer is likely to depend on how you've produced these equations. TeX stackexchange does not use a maths renderer because this a site about TeX/LaTeX not maths and because we're usually more interested in the code than the output. It's also worth mentioning that math.SE, for example, uses MathJax, which is not TeX/LaTeX, which is, in fact, off-topic here and only does maths. There isn't a renderer that could do enough for us here

Comment: Do you have the equation inside a `tabular` or `array`? If so, the spacing may be as a result of using `\multicolumn` *without* a proper inter-column space removal `@{}`...

Comment: You probably get also “arbitrary” space between words: as far as I can see from the picture, you're using narrow columns with `multicols` (that's different from `\multicolumn`). Without an example it's rather difficult to give sensible help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you maybe using an `array` or `tabular` environment to typeset the math items in columns? If so, it's a good idea to customize the `array` environment along the lines pursued in the following screenshot and example code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for columns that contain just operators, e.g., = and +

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}  % abs. value
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ip}{\langle}{\rangle} % inner prod.

\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{|cccccc}
\abs{\ip{x,y}} & = & (x'y)^2 & = & \bigl(\sum_i x_iy_i\bigr)^2 & =
\end{array}$

\medskip
versus 

\medskip
\begingroup % localize scope of the following statement
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt} % no whitespace between columns
$\begin{array}{|cCcCcC}llll % but, use "C" column type for operators
\abs{\ip{x,y}} & = & (x'y)^2 & = & \bigl(\sum_i x_iy_i\bigr)^2 & =
\end{array}$
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The spacing is never arbitrary, TeX just adds space to meet the constraints it is set by the document author.

If they are displayed equations then you should use display math mode, then it will not happen.

If you are using justified paragraphs and that is the only thing on the line then the only stretch space is around the = and so the only way it can justify the paragraph is to stretch that space to make the expression take the full width of the column.

Often ragged right setting is better than justified in narrow columns for exactly this reason (whether the space being stretched is in maths or between words).